# What kinds of metals are good for a salt shaker?

Tags: salt

What kinds of kinds metals are good for a salt shaker? Are there metals which will react with the salt in them to cause either the shaker to corrode or ruin the salt (eg. cause caking etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Stainless steel is usually best, as it won't react with salt or salty water.  It's best to avoid other steels, although you may have some luck with aluminium as long as the shaker remains dry.

High-end salt grinders use ceramic grinding elements rather than steel ones to minimise the erosion caused by the salt.

Comment: Stainless steel will pit and form stress cracks when exposed to chloride salts (including table salt) for a long time. Plastic or ceramic is really the only way to go.

Comment: No metal is perfect for continuous exposure to every kind of food, end of story; however the original question asked about metals specifically.

Comment: I was agreeing with your post, but clarifying that stainless will still react over time. And that ceramic was a better choice.